# Sci-fi serial - English language

Tags: story-identification, tv

All I remember watching English serial dubbed in my mother tongue in my childhood.
A father, who is a scientist, invents a new gadget every time.
One episode that I remember - Father (Scientist) does an experiment and travels at the speed of light. But he is unable to decelerate to normal speed. At that speed, everyone looks like frozen in his point of view. That episode is about how he contacts his family (who are at normal speed) to get himself to normal speed.

Comment: When it was? 10 years ago? 20?

Answer (score 4):

The TV Tropes page for [Time Stands Still](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeStandsStill) has this entry for an episode (season 1, episode 12, "Honey, I'm Streakin'") of [Honey, I Shrunk the Kids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids:_The_TV_Show):

> In an episode of the Honey, I Shrunk the Kids series, Wayne invents a device that speeds him up. He keeps a fancy model for himself while his boss stumbles upon the prototype. However, they then set the dial to 10, at which point everything around them slows down to extreme crawl. They attempt to turn off the devices or take them off, but the use of the untested setting results in Phlebotinum Breakdown, and they are stuck that way until Wayne thinks to use a freezer-like device to slow down their molecules to normal speed.

---

From the Wikipedia article for the show:

> It expands upon the original film's concept of a shrinking experiment gone wrong to include a myriad of experiments gone awry. It debuted in syndication on September 1, 1997 and ran for three consecutive seasons, concluding with the 66th episode on May 20, 2000.
>
> Peter Scolari took over the role of Wayne Szalinski, the wacky inventor played by Rick Moranis in the original film. Each episode incorporates new technologies and digital effects to feature the family in various new adventures.